# MySQL how to select what I need, most likely an inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, select

A bit of a newbie question, probably an INNER JOIN with an "AS" statement, but I can't figure it out...

This is for a MYSQL based competition app.  I want to select the "img_title" for both img_id1 and img_id2.  I can't figure out how to do it and still see which title is assigned to the associated _id1 or _id2.

My tables:

- competitions

  - comp_id
  - img_id1
  - img_id2
- on_deck

  - img_id
  - img_title

Desired results:
comp_id | img_id1 | img_title1 |img_id2 | img_title2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select comp_id, img_id1, b.img_title as img_title1, 
img_id2, b2.img_title as img_title2
from competitions a 
left outer join on_deck b on b.img_id = a.img_id1
left outer join on_deck b2 on b2.img_id = a.img_id2
```

switch let outer join to inner join if you want to exclude rows in competitions that do not have two matching img_ids

Answer (score 2):

You need a join for each image:

```
SELECT comp.comp_id, img1.img_id, img1.img_title, img2.img_id, img2.img_title
FROM competitions comp
INNER JOIN on_deck img1 ON img1.img_id = comp.img_id1
INNER JOIN on_deck img2 ON img2.img_id = comp.img_id2
```

`LEFT JOIN` if `img_id1` or `img_id2` can be `NULL`.

Comment: I'd have done a left join to suss out missing/ broken links, but other than that you type faster than me.:)

Comment: I think he need to select only one competition so this query is here for example. :)

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the results you want.  This also assumes that `comp.img_id1` and `comp.img_id2` are never `NULL`.

```
SELECT comp.comp_id
, comp.img_id1
, deck1.img_title AS img_title1
, comp.img_id2
, deck2.img_title AS img_title2
FROM competitions AS comp
JOIN on_deck deck1 ON comp.img_id1 = deck1.img_id
JOIN on_deck deck2 ON comp.img_id2 = deck2.img_id
```

If you have plan on having a `NULL` or empty string `comp.img_id1` and/or `comp.img_id2` fields, you'll need to do some left joins.